# What materials do I need to make a locker?

Tags: unturned

I have multiple metal sheets and metal bars, but the recipe is still not showing up for me to craft the locker. I've even tried to cheat in the locker, but there was an error and my game crashed. I have a blow torch and I have most of the materials needed to make the locker. [image: this is my friends locker not mine]

The items I have are 20 metal bars, 10 metal sheets, and a %60 blowtorch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wiki](http://unturned.wikia.com/wiki/Locker) you need:

> 3 Metal Sheet + 3 Metal Bar + Blowtorch = 1 Locker (With level 3 Craftsman).

You've stated that your Craftsman level is 5.  That means you have to be missing materials (I suppose a bugged game is always possible as well).

You can check against [this video](https://youtu.be/sgPwrEjVK9w?t=1m29s) on how to make it.  Make sure all the items needed to craft it are accounted for when attempting to create the locker.

Comment: i just checked my craftsman skill and its at 5

Comment: What are the materials you currently have?  You should edit them into your question.  Double check them all.

Comment: i have a lot of crates that have random things, let me check

Comment: i will look at the video later, but when i went back my base was destroyed so it might be a while before i can look at the video.